# Plotting bubble chart in d3.js using geojson file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, geojson

**myfile.geojson -**

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME_2": "East Godavari", "NAME_3": "Kottapeta", "profit": 326, "npa": 174.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":  [ [ [ 81.719329833984432, 16.927410125732479 ], [ 81.723800659179801, 16.961441040039119 ], [ 81.732490539550838, 16.990680694580135 ], [ 81.723800659179972, 16.961441040039119 ], [ 81.719329833984432, 16.927410125732479 ] ] ], 

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME_2": "East Godavari", "NAME_3": "Rajahmundry", "profit": 1762, "npa": 1683.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 81.717170715332031, 17.060630798339901 ], [ 81.722846984863565, 17.047969818115348 ], [ 81.731689453125, 17.009309768676758 ], [ 81.729316711425895, 17.024909973144531 ], [ 81.727096557617188, 17.035369873046875 ] ] ] 
} } ] }
```

Now,I need to add this "myfile.geojson" and plot the bubble chart using the data in "myfile.geojson".

I need to plot on the basis of "profit" value given in the myfile.geojson
 Please help..

In the following link
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

please suggest the modifications in "index.html" of bubble chart which are required for adding "myfile.geojson" in place of "flare.json", given in the above link to get the output of a bubble chart based on "profit" value of "myfile.geojson".
Please suggest the modificatons.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, please don't post a new question for the same issue before anybody had a chance to answer the previous one. You can edit your questions to add more information. Second, you need to explain how you want to add the new data (which doesn't seem to have any geographical information?).

Comment: Sorry Sir... I am just a beginner to use d3.I will edit the question and try to explain clearly Sir.... Thank you for your suggestion Sir......

Comment: You still haven't told us how the geographical information relates to the bubble chart. You can't display coordinates in a bubble chart.

Comment: Sorry Sir...I have edited the question again.I need to plot the bubble chart on the basis of "profit" value given in the myfile.geojson.

Comment: Sir...please suggest the modificatons.....

Comment: It sounds like all you need to do is extract the values from the geojson and then do what you did before.

Comment: Yes Sir.... Can you please explain how to extract the values from geojson on the basis of "profit" value

Comment: Something like `data.features.map(function(d) { return d.properties.profit; })`.

Comment: Thank you Sir...I have edited the question.

Comment: Please suggest the modifications,Sir.....

Comment: Please show some effort yourself.

Comment: I have tried Sir..but no source of informatIon.... since im just a beginner.. need your guidance Sir...please kindly help Sir.....